# Can I unsubscribe from a question's notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, unsubscribe

I answered a question on Stack Overflow and the user keeps asking for more and more help. Can I opt-out from notifications of that particular question?

Comment: You can also just delete the answer if the OP hasn't accepted it. You'll lose the rep you've gained/lost on it, but it might be worth it to get away from a relentless help vampire.

Comment: +1 for "relentless help vampire"

Comment: Another example why many (including myself) are thankful there is no private messaging system here.

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user comments on your answer you will get a notification for that. There is no direct option to opt out from the notification. However there are some alternative way to not receive notification:

- Simply ask the OP to not ask further questions on your answer. Instead tell him to search/ask different question if it can be a separate question.
- You can flag your answer for moderator's attention and simply request them to lock the post so the OP will not be able to add further comments. However you have to give a valid reason behind requesting to lock.
- You can also remove your name from your answer. So you will not get any further notification. But you will lose the reputation changes because the answer will not be associated with you after that.

Comment: but how do I remove my name? and is the flag option is the little icon that looks like a flag?

Comment: @raam86 - Flag your answer from where you want to remove your name. Go to *other* option and request moderators there.

Comment: Started as joke, Found out I didn't know how to do it :D